# Raising Sunken living room - Load concern

Tags: floor, joists, load

I want to raise the living room so it is level with the rest of the house. I have all the dimensions and how I will be doing it. However, I am concerned about the load as there is a basement below.

The joists are 2x8 spanning about 11' 8". On the outer wall, it looks the the joists are resting on double 2x4 top plates. On inner walls, most likely resting on a structural I-beam or double-quad 2x8 beams.

I want to run the joists parallel to the current joists so I can run hardwood perpendicular to joists the full length of the living room - dinning room area for a bigger room affect. I plan on putting the joists right above the current joists if I can find a meaningful way to achieve that since not all joists will be 16" on centre. IF there is a rim joist available on the outer walls, I will be using structural screws on top of resting the joists on the current floor for greater strength.

**TL/DR: Raising sunken Living room floor, basement underneath, 2x8 joists 16oc spanning 11' 8'. I am NOT removing old sublfoor and hardwood. Putting joists parallel to old joists + using structural screws IF POSSIBLE. Concerned about floor load.**

**My question: Will there be too much weight on the floor by raising it using my method?**

TIA

Comment: 2 points of clarification: 1) What size joists will you be adding on? 2) "it looks the the joists are resting on double 2x4 headers" Is this really a "header" spanning a door or window where the 2x4 are placed in the tall direction, or is this a standard 2x4 doubled top plate for the wall below?

Comment: A thought: You do _not_ want to lay your new hardwood directly on top of your new joists. They will be too soft & springy. You'll want to lay down 3/4" (or thicker) T&G plywood, then put the hardwood on top of that. The plywood won't care which direction the joists run below it, and the hardwood can go down any old way on top of plywood. TL;DR: you can put your new joists perpendicular to the old ones if that works out better.

Comment: @FreeMan with the hardwood, there is a 6 inch difference. Accounting for new 5/8 subfloor and 3/4 hardwood, I will need to rip 2x6 into 4 1/8". And oops, yes I meant double top plates, edited! So to add, I will be adding new joists + New subfloor + new hardwood to level with existing floor.